# Cannot scroll to bottom

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have the following jQuery mobile page:

```
<div id="performMeasurementPage" data-role="page">
 <div data-role="header" role="banner" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
  <h1>Measurement</h1>
  <a data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" href="" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">Care Plan </a>
 </div>
 <div data-role="content">
  <div data-content-theme="d">
   <form id="measurementForm" action="#performMeasurementPage">
    <h3>Blood Pressure</h3>
    <label for="systolic"><em>* </em>Systolic:</label>
    <input type="number" name="systolic" id="systolic" />
    <label for="diastolic">Diastolic:</label>
    <input type="number" name="diastolic" id="diastolic" />
    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
     <div class="ui-block-a">
      <h3>Temperature:</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="ui-block-b">
      <input type="number" name="temperature" id="temperature" data-theme="b"></input>
     </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <label for="slider">
      <h3>Weight:</h3>
     </label>
     <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="50" min="50" max="300" />
    </div>
    <button id="doneMeasurement" type="button" data-theme="b">Done</button>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div data-role="footer" class="ui-frame ui-frame-footer" id="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
  <h1> Footer </h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript for this page only assigns click events and validations for text box. Now, the content scrolls just fine unless I focus on any one of the text box. After the keyboard pops up and I press 'done', the content can no longer scroll, and snaps the page to the top.

Also, a thing to notice is that this behavior is repeated in Android and iOS alike.

I would appreciate any type of help in this one.

Answer (score 0):

iOS and Android both have WebKit at the core of their browsers.  Thus a bug in Mobile Safari is sometimes also in the Android browser (Chrome?).

Perhaps it would help to isolate the problem by trying it in Mobile Firefox.  It doesn't use WebKit.  That would determine whether it's a browser bug or a problem with your code.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I am however, making an application for Phonegap/Cordova. I guess I would just copy and paste one page and see how it behaves.